# EnableViewState = false - - but still seems to be "working"

Tags: c#

I'm a new C# programmer and have just created a simple program.  I first wanted it to count button clicks, maintaining the cumulative count across clicks (post backs).  This worked.

Now I want to turn off EnableViewState and see that the clicks do NOT accumulate.  So I turned off EnableViewState (EnableViewState="False") for the text box (named txtCount), but somehow it still keeps counting and accumulating my clicks across posts.  Am I missing something here? How can it be maintaining the state of this text box without ViewState on?

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = int.Parse(txtCount.Text);
        count++;
        txtCount.Text = count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend you abandon learning ASP.Net Forms. It's a dead technology and the industry has moved towards MVC pattern based web applications. A lot of the time and energy you spend learning ASP.Net Forms will be a waste.

Comment: Thanks.  This is just a short trip into Forms, and I will be soon studying MVC in detail.  But I still would like to know how this form/asp is maintaining the state of this control with the view state for it turned off.

Comment: @SpencerRuport - that is a bit harsh, don't you think? WebForms is not officially dead, as they are continuing to release new versions (i.e 4.5). I don't disagree that it would be a good idea to learn more than just WebForms, but calling it a complete waste of time is a bit heavy handed and short-sighted in my opinion.

Comment: I didn't say it'd be a complete waste of time and energy, just a lot of it. But you're right it's not "dead", that was a bit of an exaggeration on my part. Still I don't think it's worth the effort for a beginner to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both really good answers above.  A good way to remember it (and to realize why ViewState is required at all) is that standard HTML form elements (such as asp:TextBox which renders as an HTML input) will be included in the POST, whereas non-standard HTML form elements (such as asp:Label which renders as an HTML span) won't be so you have to use them with ViewState.

Try switching your asp:TextBox to an asp:Label.  You'll see that it breaks when you turn off ViewState, but it works with ViewState on.  This is because HTML span values are not included in HTML form posts.

This is a pretty good article that discusses ViewState, even though it's pretty old:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  But now I can't get it to work with an asp:Label, with ViewState on.  That is, with the same code as I posted above but now txtCount is a label, it appears to not be maintaining state across clicks.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: general questions- is the opening and closing tab asp:Label?  does the designer file have it listed as a label?  Is it rendering properly as a span in the browser?  Are there any other errors on the page preventing the ViewState from updating?  Can you set a breakpoint and see if the click event is getting called at all?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Click Count" />.  In the rendered source:
        <span id="txtCount">1</span>
        <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Click Count" id="Button1" />
         
I don't think there are any errors.  The label is initialized to 0, and is then incremented with each button click.  It makes it up to 1 on the first click, and then just stays at 1.  I'm still figuring out Visual Studio debug, so it looks like now's a good time to take the plunge into it!   thanks

Comment: If you had it working before, start over with a new ASPX page and then once the new one is working, compare the three pairs of files in something like kdiff - it should hopefully get you to the answer.

Comment: This is the label code: <asp:Label ID="txtCount" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

Answer (score 4):

You're not using `ViewState`, you're using the form element itself.  Here you read from the form element:

```
int count = int.Parse(txtCount.Text);
```

And here you write back to the form element:

```
txtCount.Text = count.ToString();
```

So the value is being stored in the `input` that's emitted to the HTML, and posted back as part of the HTTP form post.

If you want to examine this more closely, take a look at your browser's debugging tools.  (FireBug, Chrome developer tools, IE developer tools, etc.)  Look for the tab/panel/etc. where the network activity is captured.  When you click your button, you'll want to watch the POST request that's being sent to the server.

Within that POST request is a series of key/value pairs.  Every active form element on the page sends a key/value pair, and the entire viewstate is itself just a key/value pair from a hidden form element.  (Where the value is a base-64 encoded string.)  If the form element has the value in question, it's in the POST request and, thus, available server-side.

Remove the text from the text box between posts and it should stop counting.  (Probably even throw an exception on `int.Parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the difference between post back data (`Form`) and `ViewState`.

`ViewState` is actually a hidden field with encoded data that is used by ASP.NET to reconstruct certain parts of the page on postback, which is why you think you need it to be turned on for your text box example to work.

While you did not show your markup, I will pretend that this is what you have:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtCount" runat="server" text="Enter a number here" />
```

Now the user types in a number at run-time (say `7` for argument's sake) and posts the page back to the server.

The server receives two pieces of data, the post back data (`7`) via the `Form` and `ViewState`, which is the hidden field.

In your example, the `ViewState` from the text box's point of view, contains the data `Enter a number here`, while the `Form` contains the value the user actually typed into the text box.

Note: As an aside, if you look into ASP.NET MVC you will find that `ViewState` does not even exist. After learning some of the ASP.NET WebForms constructs, I recommend you read [Compatibility of ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381619%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - I will be soon focusing on MVC.